# CMake fails to find static library

Tags: cmake

CMake always prefers to find dynamic library to static:

```
find_library(SQLITE_LIBRARY sqlite3)
message(STATUS "Sqlite found: ${SQLITE_LIBRARY}")
...
-- Sqlite3 found: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
```

I'm using `Debian 7 wheezy`, `cmake 2.8.9` and `sqlite3-dev` package. 
`ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep sqlite3`:

```
libsqlite3.a
libsqlite3.la
libsqlite3.so
libsqlite3.so.0
libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

I've tried various methods that I found on internet. None of them worked:

```
1. find_library(SQLITE_LIBRARY sqlite3.a)

2. find_library(SQLITE_LIBRARY libsqlite3.a)

3. set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a)
   find_library(SQLITE_LIBRARY sqlite3)

4. set(CMAKE_FIND_STATIC FIRST)
   find_library(SQLITE_LIBRARY sqlite3)
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the sqlite3 command to properly retrieve the version:

```
find_program( SQLITE3_EXECUTABLE NAMES sqlite3DOC "Path to sqlite3 executable" )
execute_process( COMMAND ${SQLITE3_EXECUTABLE} -version OUTPUT_VARIABLE _SQLITE3_VERSION OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE )
string( REGEX MATCH "^([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)*)([ \t].*)?$" SQLITE3_VERSION "${_SQLITE3_VERSION}" )
set( SQLITE3_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}" CACHE STRING "Version of sqlite3 executable" )
find_library(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES sqlite3)
```